# Как добавить файл у которого нет расширения в json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Есть файл без расширения, как его добавить в json?

Я знаю как добавить обычный txt файл.

Скрипт:

```
data = dict()

for file_name in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        data[file_name] = f.read()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Я понимаю что там не `read` нужно вписывать, а что то другое. Бинарный режим пробовал -- тоже не получается

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос - `glob.glob('*')`, вместо `'*.txt'`

Comment: @MaxU Да только тут файл с расширением txt а там расширения нету у файла !

Comment: `glob.glob('*')` - вернет __все__ файлы (с расширенем и без)... Или вам нужны только файлы с расширением `.txt` и без расширения, игнорируя все остальные расширения?

Comment: @MaxU ДА я знаю но когда я запускаю программу он ругается          `    data[file_name] = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\kolya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 167: character maps to <undefined>
`

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы было понятно чего вы пытаетесь достичь... Пока что не очень понятно. Приведите пример списка имен файлов в директории в качестве входных данных и отфильтрованный список в качестве выходных данных.

Comment: @MaxU Данный скрипт кодирует файлы в json но когда я пишу glob.glob(*.*) он ругается на эту линию где прописан этот код data[file_name] = f.read()

Comment: У вас ошибка при чтение очередного файла. Попробуйте добавить кодировку при открытие файла `with open(file_name, encoding = 'cp866') as f:`